# Multimap output after copying from map

Tags: c++, maps, multimap

This program stores  pairs in a map, counting the number of times a word occurs. The goal is to have the data sorted by number of occurences and output in value/string form. Obviously the normal map sorts by the string key, so I had to reverse it.

To do this I read in words, and increment their values appropriately in a map. Then I create a multimap and copy the pairs from the map into the multimap, but reversed. Then I iterate through the multimap, outputting the pairs. However, a runtime error occurs when I try to output the pairs and I'm not sure why.

Here is the code:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<string, int> words;
    multimap<int, string> words2;

    string s;
    while (true) {
        cin >> s;
        if (s == "0") break;
        ++words[s];
    }

    map<string, int>::iterator p;
    for (p = words.begin(); p!=words.end(); ++p)
        words2.insert(make_pair(p->second, p->first));

    multimap<int, string>::iterator p2;
    for (p2 = words2.begin(); p2!=words2.end(); ++p2)
        cout << p->first << ": " << p->second << '\n';
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

P.S. I read in different places that multimap can have multiple occurences of a key (which is why I used it in the first place) and/or multiple values in a single key. Some clarification would be nice regarding which is true or whether both are true.

Also is there any type of copy algorithm for maps? I decided to just use a for loop for simplicity's sake, and it would probably be fairly easy to write a custom copy, but I'm just wondering (for copying maps to other pair containers and copying to output.)

Comment: Problems like that are the reason you shouldn't define the loop variable before the loop itself but inside: `for (multimap<int, string>::iterator p2 = words2.begin(); p2!=words2.end(); ++p2)`.

Comment: I didn't do it because I thought it was ugly, but correctness > readability.

Comment: You can address readability (at least to some degree) by creating typedefs for the iterator types.

Comment: The auto keyword will make all this so much easier: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Type_inference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for (p2 = words2.begin(); p2!=words2.end(); ++p2)
        cout << p->first << ": " << p->second << '\n';
```

Shouldn't the p's in your output statement be p2's ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use p rather than p2 when printing, Change the output line to:

```
cout << p2->first << ": " << p2->second << '\n';
```

This error would been avoided if you declared p in the for loop rather than before it since it would have gone out of scope after the first for loop ended.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is from 2009, but to answer the second part of the question, yes there are algorithms in `std` to copy elements between ranges. When copying between containers with the same value type, using `std::copy` with `std::inserter` will do:

```
map<string, int> wordsA;
multimap<string, int> wordsB;
copy(wordsA.begin(), words.end(), inserter(wordsB, wordsB.begin()));
```

Since you are copying to a container of different type, you can use `std::transform` to apply a tranformation function to the elements before inserting them to the second container:

```
transform(words.begin(), words.end(), 
          std::inserter(words2, words2.begin()),
          [](const pair<string, int>& x) -> pair<int, string>
          {
              return make_pair(x.second, x.first);
          }
          );
```

As is quite usual, this actually ends up to be more lines of code than your simple loop and does essentially the same :)

Please note that `std::copy`, `std::transform` etc... will work with pretty much any container from `std`. This is not specific to `std::map`. You can also use `std::front_inserter` and `std::back_inserter` with containers that have `push_front()` resp. `push_back()` methods.